# Javascript Null Error with LiveValidation

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to troubleshoot this error with the form submission. I am using the Livevalidation library in order to validate the email address field. Something isn't connecting properly to the library as I get this error in dev tools console. The library isnt getting called in under to validate the form field. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ERROR:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of null
    at LiveValidation.initialize (livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js:5)
    at new LiveValidation (livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js:5)
    at <anonymous>:2:13
    at api.min.js:2
    at Module.S (api.min.js:2)
    at t.inlineScripts (api.min.js:2)
    at api.min.js:2
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="Camp-2021-05-Aware-ParkNeedsUs-FRM-Lightbox" action="https://s989596683.t.eloqua.com/e/f2" onsubmit="return handleFormSubmit(this)" id="form210" class="elq-form">
    <input value="Camp-2021-05-Aware-ParkNeedsUs-FRM-Lightbox" type="hidden" name="elqFormName" />
    <input value="989596683" type="hidden" name="elqSiteId" />
    <input name="elqCampaignId" type="hidden" />
    <div class="layout container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid-layout-col">
                <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="formElement0" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
                        <!--div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <label class="elq-label " for="fe2045">Email Address
              </label>
            </div-->
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="field-control-wrapper" style="width: 65%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            class="elq-item-input"
                                            name="emailAddress"
                                            id="f20"
                                            style="width: 100%; font-size: 14px; color: #828282;"
                                            onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"
                                            onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue"
                                            value="Email Address"
                                            maxlength="50"
                                        />
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            var f20 = window.document.getElementById("f20");
                                        </script>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            var f20 = new LiveValidation("email");
                                            f20.add(Validate.Email);
                                        </script>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            var title = new LiveValidation("title", { onlyOnSubmit: true });
                                            title.add(Validate.Email);
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid-layout-col">
                <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="formElement1" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div align="center">
                                        <input type="Submit" class="submit-button-style" value="Submit" id="fe2046" style="margin-top: 8px; background-color: #286140; padding: 12px; border: none; width: 65%; color: white;" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://img04.en25.com/i/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks I modified my code with a validation that works better